# Quartz - .NET Core - Null Reference Exception

Tags: asp.net-core, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to implement the Quartz for .NET Core.
At the moment I have the following:

```
    public class Startup
        {
            **private IScheduler _scheduler { get; set; }//quartz**
            public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
            {
                Configuration = configuration;
                **_scheduler = ConfigureQuartz();//quartz**
            }

            public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

            public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                services.AddDbContext<Context>(options =>
                {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("notebook14"));
                });

...
...
...

                **#region for Quartz DI
                services.AddScoped<Job>();
                services.AddSingleton(provider => _scheduler);
                #endregion**

            }

            public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
            {
                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                }
                else
                {
                    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                    app.UseHsts();
                }
                app.UseHttpsRedirection();
                app.UseStaticFiles();

                app.UseRouting();

                app.UseAuthentication();
                app.UseAuthorization();

                app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                {

                    endpoints.MapControllers();
                    endpoints.MapRazorPages();

                 endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                });

            }
            **#region for Quartz
            private IScheduler ConfigureQuartz()
            {

                NameValueCollection properties = new NameValueCollection()
                {
                    {"quartz.serializer.type","binary"}
                };
                StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
                _scheduler = factory.GetScheduler().Result;
                _scheduler.Start();

                return _scheduler;
            }

            #endregion**
```

...and Program.cs because I would like to start a schedule at first deploy and then run the task every day:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
                UserManager<AppUser> userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<AppUser>>();
                RoleManager<AppRole> roleManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<AppRole>>();

                **IScheduler scheduler = services.GetRequiredService<IScheduler>();
                Start.StartSchedule(scheduler);**

                Init.AssignAdmin(userManager, roleManager).Wait();
            }
            host.Run();

        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

...and Start.cs, where I have created the job and the trigger :

```
 public class Start
    {
        public static Context _context { get; set; }
        public Start(Context context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public async static void StartSchedule(IScheduler _scheduler)
        {
            IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<Job>().WithIdentity("Generate", "FreeSlots").Build();

            ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create().WithIdentity("Trigger", "FreeSlots").StartNow()
                .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule(t=>t.StartingDailyAt(new TimeOfDay(10,59)))
                .Build();

            await _scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
        }
    }
```

...and finally, the Job itself:

```
public class Job : IJob
    {
        public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("TRIGGERED!");
                List<AppUser> doctors = Start._context.Users.Where(x => x.Type == AppUser.UserType.Doctor).ToList();

                DateTime First = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 8, 0, 0);

                List<Appointments> appointments = new List<Appointments>()
            {
                new Appointments(){Date=First, Time=First,Status=Appointments.SlotStatus.Free},
                new Appointments(){Date=First, Time=First.AddHours(1),Status=Appointments.SlotStatus.Free},
                new Appointments(){Date=First, Time=First.AddHours(2),Status=Appointments.SlotStatus.Free},
                new Appointments(){Date=First, Time=First.AddHours(3),Status=Appointments.SlotStatus.Free},
                new Appointments(){Date=First, Time=First.AddHours(4),Status=Appointments.SlotStatus.Free},
                new Appointments(){Date=First, Time=First.AddHours(5),Status=Appointments.SlotStatus.Free},
                new Appointments(){Date=First, Time=First.AddHours(6),Status=Appointments.SlotStatus.Free},
                new Appointments(){Date=First, Time=First.AddHours(7),Status=Appointments.SlotStatus.Free},
                new Appointments(){Date=First, Time=First.AddHours(8),Status=Appointments.SlotStatus.Free},

            };

                foreach (AppUser doc in doctors)
                {
                    foreach (Appointments slot in appointments)
                    {
                        slot.DoctorId = doc.Id;
                        Start._context.Appointments.Add(slot);
                        Start._context.SaveChanges();
                        var message = "Slot for " + slot.DoctorId.ToString() + " " + slot.Time + " " + slot.Status;
                        Console.WriteLine(message);
                    }

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that I get a null reference exception when the Job is executed:
[image]

Does anybody have any ideas? Is there a way to make this work? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Don't post screenshots. Post the *actual* exception text returned by `Exception.ToString()`. That includes any inner exceptions and the stack trace with the calls that led to the error. You can just click on `Copy Details` to get all that information and paste it in the question.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine` won't throw such an exception because `WriteLine` is a static method. Perhaps the exception is thrown in a different line, perhaps something weird is going on with the standard output stream and something inside `WriteLine` throws? Web applications typically have no console so you should use `ILogger` for logging

Comment: Details: System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=PRENATALv2
  StackTrace:
   at PRENATALv2.QuartzSchedule.Job.Execute(IJobExecutionContext context) in C:\Users\user\Desktop\_rs1 -nova18 -quartz -appoint\_rs1 -nova18 -quartz -appoint\PRENATALv2\PRENATALv2\QuartzSchedule\Job.cs:line 17

Comment: No matter what I write in the execute method i get the same exception :)

Comment: The only way this would happen would be to define a `Console` field or property and forget to initialise it. In any case, this is *not* an appropriate way to log anything

Comment: Like I said, no matter what I write in the Execute function of Job.cs I am getting the same error (on the first line of the execute function). It seems like the Job.cs is not allocated !?